How to remove line within tables?
I'm trying to remove a line/lines before some images that are inside a row in more than one table in document.
The part of the table looks like this and line above the images is shown by the black arrow.


This is my current code but is not removing anything
Sub RemoveLine()
Dim oTable As Table
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oFind As Range
   
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    
        Set oRng = oTable.Range
        Set oFind = oTable.Range
        
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:="[^13^l]{1,}", MatchWildcards:=True)
                If oFind.InRange(oRng) Then
                    oFind.Text = ""
                End If
            Loop
        End With

    Next oTable

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set oTable = Nothing
Set oRng = Nothing

End Sub

Udpate
After run code of @taller, it deletes in some cases and doesn´t delete in other cases. I see the variable sText in both cases and looks like below in each case. This is a sample file.


Maybe try adjusting Paragraph >> Space before to zero.  Can you remove that spacing manually?  How would you do that?

manually can not be remove either. If i activate the  "Show/Hide paragraphs marks", it shows a black square with a circle inside and since there are many similar cases for which remove that lines, is better something automated. Please se my update image

That looks like an empty cell above the images? (split cell?) Try setting all cell borders to visible and what does it look like?

I changed the color and it seems that is a cell. Please see the image I added


Loop through all cells and remove the nested table located at the top of each cell range.

Note: Backup your file before testing.


Sub RemoveNestedTable()
    Dim mainTable As Table, oCell As Cell
    Dim cellRange As Range, sText As String, i As Long
    If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        ' loop through table
        For Each mainTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
            ' loop through cells
            For Each oCell In mainTable.Range.Cells
                Set cellRange = oCell.Range
                sText = cellRange.Text
                If Left(sText, 5) = Chr(13) & Chr(7) & Chr(13) & Chr(7) & Chr(47) Then
                    cellRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
                    ' nested table
                    If cellRange.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                        cellRange.Tables(1).Delete
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub




Question: if there is another way to identify only the nested table that is especifically at the top of the cell?

Sub NestedTab()
    Dim t As Table, tt As Table
    Dim c As cell
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each c In t.Range.Cells
            If c.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                For Each tt In c.Tables
                    If tt.Range.Start = c.Range.Start Then
                        tt.Delete
                    End If
                Next tt
            End If
        Next c
    Next t
End Sub


Thanks for your great help. I've run your solution and it works partially. In some cases deletes the nested table and sometimes doesn´t. Checking the variable "sText" I see some difference in each case. Please see my update. Additionally, I've added the link for a sample file if you can have  look. I've colorized the nested table only to make it easier to see it, in the actual file, the nested tables don't have color.

And finally, how do you identify that there are those invisible characters there? since you use a concatenation of Chr(13), Char(7) and Chr(47)

I was able to set the condition for the other case. Thank you

There is an extra Space between the table and image. https://i.sstatic.net/IxRG7QbW.png

}Thank you. Not sure is that extra space causes not to be deleted, what I say is the first 5 characters in the second case for sText are Char 13,7,13,7,32. And in first case (what you set) the chars are 13,7,13,7,47. I've added and "or" with those new characters sequence and it seems to work. Not sure is there is another way to identify if there is a nested able within a row.

If you are pretty sure to remove all nested table which is at the begging of a cell, pls change to If Left(sText, 4) = Chr(13) & Chr(7) & Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then.  It will delete all nested tables in your sample file.

Yes, only setting the comparison for 4 characters, remove "both types" of nested tables, all nested within the current cell, not only what is at the top. Thanks again. What I have the doubt if there is another way to identify only the nested table that is especifically at the top of the cell?

I've post a snippet to remove all nested tables.

Thanks a lot. I cannot upvote twice if not I'd do it.
